# Bucle infinito en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi

Actualmente estoy trabajando en un proyecto donde nesesito **hacer un bucle infinito a un codigo de python** de manera que se actualicen los datos que estoy pidiendo a una base de datos .json cada cierto tiempo.

**El codigo es el siguiente:**

```
from RPLCD import CharLCD
import json
import requests
import time

lcd = CharLCD(cols=16, rows=2, pin_rs=37, pin_e=35, pins_data=[33, 31, 29, 23]) #definimos los pines
lcd2 = CharLCD(cols=16, rows=2, pin_rs=37, pin_e=35, pins_data=[33, 31, 29, 23]) #definimos los pines



url = 'https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json' #url
response = requests.get(url)

if response.status_code == 200: #si status = 200 se ejecuta esto

    lcd.write_string(u'Bitcoin Tracker\n\rBy ElTallerDeTD')
    time.sleep(4)
    lcd.clear()
    lcd2.cursor_pos = (0, 0)
    lcd2.write_string(time.strftime("Hora: "+"%H:%M"))
    time.sleep(1)
    lcd.cursor_pos = (1, 0) #pos seteada segunda fila primera columna
    data = json.loads(response.text)
    val_dol = data['bpi']['USD']['rate']+"  " #busca el valor en la ubicacion en USD
    val_eur = data['bpi']['EUR']['rate']+"  " #busca el valor en la ubicacion en EUR
    val_gbp = data['bpi']['GBP']['rate']+"" #busca el valor en la ubicacion en GBP

#########################################################################################

    framebuffer = [
        '',
        '',
    ]

    def write_to_lcd(lcd, framebuffer, num_cols):
        lcd.home()
        for row in framebuffer:
            lcd.write_string(row.ljust(num_cols)[:num_cols])
            lcd.write_string('\r\n')

    write_to_lcd(lcd, framebuffer, 16)


    long_string = 'BTC/USD: '+val_dol+'BTC/EUR: '+val_eur+'BTC/GBP: '+val_gbp

    def loop_string(string, lcd, framebuffer, row, num_cols, delay=0.8): #DELAY= CONTROLS THE SPEED OF SCROLL
        padding = ' ' * num_cols
        s = padding + string + padding
        for i in range(len(s) - num_cols + 1):
            framebuffer[row] = s[i:i+num_cols]
            write_to_lcd(lcd, framebuffer, num_cols)
            time.sleep(delay)

    while True:
        loop_string(long_string, lcd, framebuffer, 1, 16)
```

*Alguna idea de como hacer?* **Gracias de antemano!**

Comment: ¿cual es tu pregunta?

Comment: @eyllanesc Como puedo aplicar un bucle infinito a ese codigo

Comment: `... url = 'https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json' #url while True: response = requests.get(url) ....`

Comment: Un bucle infinito es un `while True:` y veo que ya tienes uno en tu código. No se entiende qué parte de tu código quieres ejecutar en bucle. Por otro lado ¿está bien la indentación? ¿Realmente estás definiendo funciones dentro del cuerpo de un `if`?

Comment: Hola @abulafia la idea es que me codigo se "reincie" para que el precio del bitcoin que estoy pidiendo se refresque al igual que la hora en la pantalla LCD donde muestro los datos. Con respecto a la indentacion puede que haya algo mal no se mucho de python y por eso la funcion esta definida dentro del if. Espero que puedas ayudarme

Comment: para hacer un bucle infinito solo debes de poner: while True: (lo que quieras que se repita)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si no lo he entendido mal, tu problema se resumiría en lo siguiente:

1. Quiero averiguar qué hora es, y qué cambio tiene el bitcoin en esa hora
2. Quiero mostrar en un LCD ambos datos (aunque no has especificado qué debe verse exactamente en las dos líneas de que dispones)
3. Quiero volver al paso 1 cada N segundos

El código que has presentado parece una mezcla construida mediante corta&pega de diferentes lugares. Hay una función llamada `write_to_lcd()`, sin documentación de qué es lo que hace, que aparentemente vuelca tantas líneas como elementos tenga la lista `framebuffer` que recibe como parámetro, "truncando" lo mostrado a sólo los primeros `numcol` letras.

Otra función llamada `loop_string()`, también sin documentar, aparentemente se ocupa de llamar sucesivas veces a `write_to_lcd()`, pasándole un framebuffer ligeramente modificado en cada iteración, para que el efecto sea que el texto mostrado en el lcd "haga scroll" horizontal.

Suponiendo que queremos hacer uso de estas funciones ya dadas, lo primero sería definirlas al inicio del programa, y no dentro de un `if` tal como están ahora. Lo segundo sería dar a tu programa esta estructura:

```
repetir infinitas veces:
    tomar qué hora es
    tomar la cotización del bitcoin
    mostrar esa información en el display
    dormir un tiempo (por ejemplo 1s)
```

La parte sencilla es la de repetir infinito, pues es simplemente `while True`. El resto tampoco es tan complicado pues ya lo tienes escrito en tu programa. Todo consiste en organizarlo mejor. Escribiremos una función para obtener qué hora es. Otra para obtener el cambio del bitcoin, y otras dos (que ya estaban en tu código) para mostrar datos. No entiendo la razón de que instancies dos displays exactamente con los mismos parámetros, así que lo he reducido a uno.

Lee el código y sus comentarios para entender cómo funciona a ver si es lo que pedías.

```
from RPLCD import CharLCD
import json
import requests
import time

def get_time():
    """Esta función retorna la hora actual en el formato a mostrar en el display"""
    return time.strftime("Hora: "+"%H:%M")

def get_bpi():
    """Esta función retorna el 'long_string' con las cotizaciones del bitcoin
    tal como queremos que aparezca en el display"""
    url = 'https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json' #url
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200: #si status = 200 se ejecuta esto
        data = json.loads(response.text)
        val_dol = data['bpi']['USD']['rate']+"  " #busca el valor en la ubicacion en USD
        val_eur = data['bpi']['EUR']['rate']+"  " #busca el valor en la ubicacion en EUR
        val_gbp = data['bpi']['GBP']['rate']+"" #busca el valor en la ubicacion en GBP
        return "BTC/USD: {} BTC/EUR: {} BTC/GBP: {}".format(val_dol, val_eur, val_gbp)
    else:
        return "Cotizaciones no disponibles"

def write_to_lcd(lcd, framebuffer, num_cols):
    """Esta funcion vuelca un framebuffer a un display, truncándolo a los num_clos
    primeros caracteres"""
    lcd.home()
    for row in framebuffer:
        lcd.write_string(row.ljust(num_cols)[:num_cols])
        lcd.write_string('\r\n')

def loop_string(string, lcd, framebuffer, row, num_cols, delay=0.8):
    """Esta función prepara una fila del framebuffer recibido de modo que
    muestre la cadena recibida como primer parámetro desplazándose hacia
    la izquierda hasta haberla mostrado completa y luego retorna.
    El parámetro 'delay' controla la velocidad del desplazamiento"""
    padding = ' ' * num_cols
    s = padding + string + padding
    for i in range(len(s) - num_cols + 1):
        framebuffer[row] = s[i:i+num_cols]
        write_to_lcd(lcd, framebuffer, num_cols)
        time.sleep(delay)


# Programa principal

# Inicizar el LCD
lcd = CharLCD(cols=16, rows=2, pin_rs=37, pin_e=35, pins_data=[33, 31, 29, 23]) #definimos los pines

# Mostrar mensaje inicial 4 segundos
lcd.write_string(u'Bitcoin Tracker\n\rBy ElTallerDeTD')
time.sleep(4)
lcd.clear()

framebuffer = ['', ''] # Información a mostrar en cada fila del LCD

while True:
    framebuffer[0] = get_time()  # Actualizar la hora en cada iteración del bucle
    long_string = get_bpi()

    # Mostrar hora y texto deslizante con la cotización
    loop_string(long_string, lcd, framebuffer, 1, 16, 0.3)
    # Esperar 1 seg y repetir bucle
    time.sleep(1)
```

Fíjate en un detalle. La función `loop_string()` va a tardar un rato en retornar ya que hasta que no ha terminado de desplazar la cadena y la ha mostrado entera, no vuelve. Según la longitud de esa cadena y el parámetro `delay`, tardará más o menos en terminar. Una vez haya terminado, `time.sleep(1)` duerme un segundo, que se suma al tiempo invertido por `loop_string()`. Si por ejemplo `loop_string()` tarda 4 segundos en terminar, entonces el bucle infinto se repetiría cada 4+1=5 segundos. La hora (y la cotización del bitcoin) no se actualizan por tanto "en tiempo real", sino sólo cada ese tiempo.

Comment: Excelente explicación! Te agradezco mucho por los comentarios,como un novato de python me sirvió mucho. Gracias!